# BufferedReader.lines() method locking up on Windows

Tags: java

I have code that invokes BufferedReader.lines().

```
EIPLogManager2.getServerLogger().info("Got header row: " + headerRow); //TODO delete this

            List<String> allBatches = reader.lines()
                    .skip(forkCount > 0 ? forkCount * forkSize : 0)
                    .limit(transactionsRemaining.get() * forkSize)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            EIPLogManager2.getServerLogger().info("Got all batches. Size: " + allBatches.size()); //TODO delete this
```

Let me explain how this code is behaving:

1. Run it on my Mac. Works perfectly.
2. Run it on Windows. The header row log entry prints out, but the Got all batches log entry never does. It seems to freeze during the stream.

The transactionsRemaining.get() call is to an AtomicInteger.

I don't know why this is happening on Windows. It makes no sense. I've seen this behavior with JRE 8 and JRE 11.

Comment: Did you try without skip and limit ?

Comment: What are you reading from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was dumb. So the forkSize and transactionsRemaining variables are set by user input. The user had set transactionsRemaining to 1,000,000,000, so the math on limit() was producing a value larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE. An IllegalArgumentException was then being thrown, and I guess I didn't have anything in place that was reporting that exception to me.

The problem is now resolved.

Comment: So your question should be deleted. It had nothing to do with Windows, and you never bothered to follow up the questions you were askded.